# Windows Mobile/Embedded Device Emulator on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-mobile-emulator

We design and develop applications that run on Windows Mobile and Windows Embedded, as this is the operating system that comes on most industrial bar code scanners right now.

Give that, we often use the Windows Mobile Device Emulator to simulate our software and give customer demonstrations.  With Windows 8 being released, it seems that the Windows Mobile Device Center no longer works.  This component was required to "Cradle" the device to get a network connection.

Is there a way to get the Windows Mobile/Embedded emulator to work on Windows 8?

Comment: What kind of error do you experience? We got the Mobile Device Center as well as the Device Emulator working on Windows 8 without additional efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uninstall `Windows Mobile Device Center`and to install the most recent one (dec 2012).

Go to the `Microsoft` web and download `Windows Mobile Device Center for Vista` (32 or 64 bits according your hardware). There is not option for `Windows 8`, but the version for `Vista` works perfectly in `Windows 8`.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use Windows CE versions for using on your mobile/ embedded projects